# DirectX 11 Render to Texture Not Working

Tags: directx-11

I want to render one triangle to texture and then that render to texture need to be displayed in a smaller size at top-left corner of screen with the original triangle at center of the screen.

I have developed one application but not succeeded. Please help me on this.
My code is as follows -

```html
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d11_1.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <directxmath.h>
#include <directxcolors.h>
#include "resource.h"

using namespace DirectX;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Structures
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct SimpleVertex
{
    XMFLOAT3 Pos;
};


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Global Variables
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HINSTANCE               g_hInst = nullptr;
HWND                    g_hWnd = nullptr;
D3D_DRIVER_TYPE         g_driverType = D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_NULL;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL       g_featureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;
ID3D11Device*           g_pd3dDevice = nullptr;
ID3D11Device1*          g_pd3dDevice1 = nullptr;
ID3D11DeviceContext*    g_pImmediateContext = nullptr;
ID3D11DeviceContext1*   g_pImmediateContext1 = nullptr;
IDXGISwapChain*         g_pSwapChain = nullptr;
IDXGISwapChain1*        g_pSwapChain1 = nullptr;
ID3D11RenderTargetView* g_pRenderTargetView = nullptr;
ID3D11VertexShader*     g_pVertexShader = nullptr;
ID3D11PixelShader*      g_pPixelShader = nullptr;
ID3D11InputLayout*      g_pVertexLayout = nullptr;
ID3D11Buffer*           g_pVertexBuffer = nullptr;


ID3D11Texture2D* m_renderTargetTexture=nullptr;
ID3D11RenderTargetView* m_renderTargetView=nullptr;
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* m_shaderResourceView=nullptr;
ID3D11DepthStencilView* m_depthStencilView;
ID3D11Texture2D* m_depthStencilBuffer;
ID3D11DepthStencilState* m_depthStencilState;



//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Forward declarations
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitWindow( HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow );
HRESULT InitDevice();
void CleanupDevice();
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );
void Render();
void RenderOnTexture();


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Entry point to the program. Initializes everything and goes into a message processing 
// loop. Idle time is used to render the scene.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int WINAPI wWinMain( _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( hPrevInstance );
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( lpCmdLine );

    if( FAILED( InitWindow( hInstance, nCmdShow ) ) )
        return 0;

    if( FAILED( InitDevice() ) )
    {
        CleanupDevice();
        return 0;
    }

    // Main message loop
    MSG msg = {0};
    while( WM_QUIT != msg.message )
    {
        if( PeekMessage( &msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
        else
        {
            Render();
        }
    }

    CleanupDevice();

    return ( int )msg.wParam;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Register class and create window
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitWindow( HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow )
{
    // Register class
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof( WNDCLASSEX );
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon( hInstance, ( LPCTSTR )IDI_TUTORIAL1 );
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor( nullptr, IDC_ARROW );
    wcex.hbrBackground = ( HBRUSH )( COLOR_WINDOW + 1 );
    wcex.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"TutorialWindowClass";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon( wcex.hInstance, ( LPCTSTR )IDI_TUTORIAL1 );
    if( !RegisterClassEx( &wcex ) )
        return E_FAIL;

    // Create window
    g_hInst = hInstance;
    RECT rc = { 0, 0, 800, 600 };
    AdjustWindowRect( &rc, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE );
    g_hWnd = CreateWindow( L"TutorialWindowClass", L"Direct3D 11 Tutorial 2: Rendering a Triangle",
                           WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
                           CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance,
                           nullptr );
    if( !g_hWnd )
        return E_FAIL;

    ShowWindow( g_hWnd, nCmdShow );

    return S_OK;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Helper for compiling shaders with D3DCompile
//
// With VS 11, we could load up prebuilt .cso files instead...
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT CompileShaderFromFile( WCHAR* szFileName, LPCSTR szEntryPoint, LPCSTR szShaderModel, ID3DBlob** ppBlobOut )
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    DWORD dwShaderFlags = D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS;
#ifdef _DEBUG
    // Set the D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG flag to embed debug information in the shaders.
    // Setting this flag improves the shader debugging experience, but still allows 
    // the shaders to be optimized and to run exactly the way they will run in 
    // the release configuration of this program.
    dwShaderFlags |= D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG;

    // Disable optimizations to further improve shader debugging
    dwShaderFlags |= D3DCOMPILE_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION;
#endif

    ID3DBlob* pErrorBlob = nullptr;
    hr = D3DCompileFromFile( szFileName, nullptr, nullptr, szEntryPoint, szShaderModel, 
        dwShaderFlags, 0, ppBlobOut, &pErrorBlob );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        if( pErrorBlob )
        {
            OutputDebugStringA( reinterpret_cast<const char*>( pErrorBlob->GetBufferPointer() ) );
            pErrorBlob->Release();
        }
        return hr;
    }
    if( pErrorBlob ) pErrorBlob->Release();

    return S_OK;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create Direct3D device and swap chain
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitDevice()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect( g_hWnd, &rc );
    UINT width = rc.right - rc.left;
    UINT height = rc.bottom - rc.top;

    UINT createDeviceFlags = 0;
#ifdef _DEBUG
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverTypes[] =
    {
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE,
    };
    UINT numDriverTypes = ARRAYSIZE( driverTypes );

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    };
 UINT numFeatureLevels = ARRAYSIZE( featureLevels );

    for( UINT driverTypeIndex = 0; driverTypeIndex < numDriverTypes; driverTypeIndex++ )
    {
        g_driverType = driverTypes[driverTypeIndex];
        hr = D3D11CreateDevice( nullptr, g_driverType, nullptr, createDeviceFlags, featureLevels, numFeatureLevels,
                                D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &g_pd3dDevice, &g_featureLevel, &g_pImmediateContext );

        if ( hr == E_INVALIDARG )
        {
            // DirectX 11.0 platforms will not recognize D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1 so we need to retry without it
            hr = D3D11CreateDevice( nullptr, g_driverType, nullptr, createDeviceFlags, &featureLevels[1], numFeatureLevels - 1,
                                    D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &g_pd3dDevice, &g_featureLevel, &g_pImmediateContext );
        }

        if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
            break;
    }
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    // Obtain DXGI factory from device (since we used nullptr for pAdapter above)
    IDXGIFactory1* dxgiFactory = nullptr;
    {
        IDXGIDevice* dxgiDevice = nullptr;
        hr = g_pd3dDevice->QueryInterface( __uuidof(IDXGIDevice), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&dxgiDevice) );
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            IDXGIAdapter* adapter = nullptr;
            hr = dxgiDevice->GetAdapter(&adapter);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = adapter->GetParent( __uuidof(IDXGIFactory1), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&dxgiFactory) );
                adapter->Release();
            }
            dxgiDevice->Release();
        }
    }
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    // Create swap chain
    IDXGIFactory2* dxgiFactory2 = nullptr;
    hr = dxgiFactory->QueryInterface( __uuidof(IDXGIFactory2), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&dxgiFactory2) );
    if ( dxgiFactory2 )
    {
        // DirectX 11.1 or later
        hr = g_pd3dDevice->QueryInterface( __uuidof(ID3D11Device1), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&g_pd3dDevice1) );
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            (void) g_pImmediateContext->QueryInterface( __uuidof(ID3D11DeviceContext1), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&g_pImmediateContext1) );
        }

        DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 sd;
        ZeroMemory(&sd, sizeof(sd));
        sd.Width = width;
        sd.Height = height;
        sd.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
        sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
        sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
        sd.BufferCount = 1;

        hr = dxgiFactory2->CreateSwapChainForHwnd( g_pd3dDevice, g_hWnd, &sd, nullptr, nullptr, &g_pSwapChain1 );
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = g_pSwapChain1->QueryInterface( __uuidof(IDXGISwapChain), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&g_pSwapChain) );
        }

        dxgiFactory2->Release();
    }
    else
    {
        // DirectX 11.0 systems
        DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
        ZeroMemory(&sd, sizeof(sd));
        sd.BufferCount = 1;
        sd.BufferDesc.Width = width;
        sd.BufferDesc.Height = height;
        sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
        sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
        sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
        sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
        sd.OutputWindow = g_hWnd;
        sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
        sd.Windowed = TRUE;

        hr = dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChain( g_pd3dDevice, &sd, &g_pSwapChain );
    }

    // Note this tutorial doesn't handle full-screen swapchains so we block the ALT+ENTER shortcut
    dxgiFactory->MakeWindowAssociation( g_hWnd, DXGI_MWA_NO_ALT_ENTER );

    dxgiFactory->Release();

    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    // Create a render target view
    ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBuffer = nullptr;
    hr = g_pSwapChain->GetBuffer( 0, __uuidof( ID3D11Texture2D ), reinterpret_cast<void**>( &pBackBuffer ) );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView( pBackBuffer, nullptr, &g_pRenderTargetView );
    pBackBuffer->Release();
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
 HRESULT result;
 D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC renderTargetViewDesc;
 D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDesc;

 // Initialize the render target texture description.
 ZeroMemory(&textureDesc, sizeof(textureDesc));

 // Setup the render target texture description.
 textureDesc.Width = 400/*textureWidth*/;
 textureDesc.Height = 400/*textureHeight*/;
 textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
 textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
 textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
 textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
 textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
 textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
 textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
 textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

 // Create the render target texture.
 result = g_pd3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &m_renderTargetTexture);
 if (FAILED(result))
 {
  return false;
 }

 // Setup the description of the render target view.
 renderTargetViewDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
 renderTargetViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
 renderTargetViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;


 // Create the render target view.
 result = g_pd3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(m_renderTargetTexture, &renderTargetViewDesc, &m_renderTargetView);
 if (FAILED(result))
 {
  return false;
 }

 // Setup the description of the shader resource view.
 shaderResourceViewDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
 shaderResourceViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
 shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
 shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

 // Create the shader resource view.
 result = g_pd3dDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(m_renderTargetTexture, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &m_shaderResourceView);



 //D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthBufferDesc;
 //D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depthStencilDesc;
 //D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilViewDesc;
 //// Initialize the description of the depth buffer.
 //ZeroMemory(&depthBufferDesc, sizeof(depthBufferDesc));

 //// Set up the description of the depth buffer.
 //depthBufferDesc.Width = 400;
 //depthBufferDesc.Height = 400;
 //depthBufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
 //depthBufferDesc.ArraySize = 1;
 //depthBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
 //depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
 //depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
 //depthBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
 //depthBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
 //depthBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
 //depthBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

 //// Create the texture for the depth buffer using the filled out description.
 //result = g_pd3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&depthBufferDesc, NULL, &m_depthStencilBuffer);
 //if (FAILED(result))
 //{
 // return false;
 //}

 //// Initialize the description of the stencil state.
 //ZeroMemory(&depthStencilDesc, sizeof(depthStencilDesc));

 //// Set up the description of the stencil state.
 //depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = true;
 //depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
 //depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;

 //depthStencilDesc.StencilEnable = true;
 //depthStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
 //depthStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

 //// Stencil operations if pixel is front-facing.
 //depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
 //depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
 //depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
 //depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

 //// Stencil operations if pixel is back-facing.
 //depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
 //depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
 //depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
 //depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

 //// Create the depth stencil state.
 //result = g_pd3dDevice->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthStencilDesc, &m_depthStencilState);
 //if (FAILED(result))
 //{
 // return false;
 //}

 //// Set the depth stencil state.
 //g_pImmediateContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(m_depthStencilState, 1);

 //// Initialize the depth stencil view.
 //ZeroMemory(&depthStencilViewDesc, sizeof(depthStencilViewDesc));

 //// Set up the depth stencil view description.
 //depthStencilViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
 //depthStencilViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
 //depthStencilViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

 //// Create the depth stencil view.
 //result = g_pd3dDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilBuffer, &depthStencilViewDesc, &m_depthStencilView);
 //if (FAILED(result))
 //{
 // return false;
 //}

 // Bind the render target view and depth stencil buffer to the output render pipeline.
 g_pImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_renderTargetView, /*m_depthStencilView*/nullptr);

 // Clear the back buffer.
 g_pImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView(m_renderTargetView, Colors::Red);

 // Clear the depth buffer.
 //g_pImmediateContext->ClearDepthStencilView(depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Setup the viewport
    D3D11_VIEWPORT vp;
    vp.Width = (FLOAT)width;
    vp.Height = (FLOAT)height;
    vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    vp.TopLeftX = 0;
    vp.TopLeftY = 0;
    g_pImmediateContext->RSSetViewports( 1, &vp );

    // Compile the vertex shader
    ID3DBlob* pVSBlob = nullptr;
    hr = CompileShaderFromFile( L"Tutorial02.fx", "VS", "vs_4_0", &pVSBlob );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        MessageBox( nullptr,
                    L"The FX file cannot be compiled.  Please run this executable from the directory that contains the FX file.", L"Error", MB_OK );
        return hr;
    }

 // Create the vertex shader
 hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateVertexShader( pVSBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pVSBlob->GetBufferSize(), nullptr, &g_pVertexShader );
 if( FAILED( hr ) )
 { 
  pVSBlob->Release();
        return hr;
 }

    // Define the input layout
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
    {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    };
 UINT numElements = ARRAYSIZE( layout );

    // Create the input layout
 hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateInputLayout( layout, numElements, pVSBlob->GetBufferPointer(),
                                          pVSBlob->GetBufferSize(), &g_pVertexLayout );
 pVSBlob->Release();
 if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    // Set the input layout
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetInputLayout( g_pVertexLayout );

 // Compile the pixel shader
 ID3DBlob* pPSBlob = nullptr;
    hr = CompileShaderFromFile( L"Tutorial02.fx", "PS", "ps_4_0", &pPSBlob );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        MessageBox( nullptr,
                    L"The FX file cannot be compiled.  Please run this executable from the directory that contains the FX file.", L"Error", MB_OK );
        return hr;
    }

 // Create the pixel shader
 hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreatePixelShader( pPSBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pPSBlob->GetBufferSize(), nullptr, &g_pPixelShader );
 pPSBlob->Release();
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    // Create vertex buffer
    SimpleVertex vertices[] =
    {
        XMFLOAT3( 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f ),
        XMFLOAT3( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f ),
        XMFLOAT3( -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f ),
    };
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
 ZeroMemory( &bd, sizeof(bd) );
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( SimpleVertex ) * 3;
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
 bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
 ZeroMemory( &InitData, sizeof(InitData) );
    InitData.pSysMem = vertices;
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &g_pVertexBuffer );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    // Set vertex buffer
    UINT stride = sizeof( SimpleVertex );
    UINT offset = 0;
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, &g_pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset );

    // Set primitive topology
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology( D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST );

 RenderOnTexture();
    return S_OK;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Clean up the objects we've created
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CleanupDevice()
{
    if( g_pImmediateContext ) g_pImmediateContext->ClearState();

    if( g_pVertexBuffer ) g_pVertexBuffer->Release();
    if( g_pVertexLayout ) g_pVertexLayout->Release();
    if( g_pVertexShader ) g_pVertexShader->Release();
    if( g_pPixelShader ) g_pPixelShader->Release();
    if( g_pRenderTargetView ) g_pRenderTargetView->Release();
    if( g_pSwapChain1 ) g_pSwapChain1->Release();
    if( g_pSwapChain ) g_pSwapChain->Release();
    if( g_pImmediateContext1 ) g_pImmediateContext1->Release();
    if( g_pImmediateContext ) g_pImmediateContext->Release();
    if( g_pd3dDevice1 ) g_pd3dDevice1->Release();
    if( g_pd3dDevice ) g_pd3dDevice->Release();
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Called every time the application receives a message
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch( message )
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint( hWnd, &ps );
        EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage( 0 );
        break;

        // Note that this tutorial does not handle resizing (WM_SIZE) requests,
        // so we created the window without the resize border.

    default:
        return DefWindowProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
    }

    return 0;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Render a frame
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Render()
{
    // Clear the back buffer 
    g_pImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView( g_pRenderTargetView, Colors::MidnightBlue );

    // Render a triangle
 /*g_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader( g_pVertexShader, nullptr, 0 );
 g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader( g_pPixelShader, nullptr, 0 );
    g_pImmediateContext->Draw( 3, 0 );*/

 g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &m_shaderResourceView);
    // Present the information rendered to the back buffer to the front buffer (the screen)
    g_pSwapChain->Present( 0, 0 );
}

void RenderOnTexture()
{
 g_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader(g_pVertexShader, nullptr, 0);
 g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader(g_pPixelShader, nullptr, 0);
 g_pImmediateContext->Draw(3, 0);
 g_pImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &g_pRenderTargetView, nullptr);
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Generally SO doesn't work well for 'debug my code' posts. You may want to take a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) tutorials, specifically [this lesson](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20custom%20shaders).

Answer (score 0):

Your Render() function has no draw calls in it.